# Memcache on appengine - how to get all data from cache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm using memcache on appengine.
I have some items which are stuck in the memcache.
I'm interested in this data.
How can I get all the data in memcache?

Also is there a way to get the data on memcache from my remote computer and not only on the app running on appengine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcache is a pure key-value store. As such, it doesn't have list operations (which could be very slow on e.g. a 500GB memcache). There is a [`flush_all` method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache) if you're looking to clear out the memcache entirely.

If you're concerned about expiring items from memcache, consider [explicitly setting a time-based expiration with the `time=` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache).

Comment: I need the data in memcache and I need a way to get all the data, before I flush it.